# R crash using xml2 package in a loop

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, xml2

I have a directory with approximately 46000 links (I called links3) and I want to scrape each of them with the following code:

```
library(reshape)
library(plyr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

base <- matrix(, nrow = (nrow(links3)), ncol = 19)
basedes <- matrix(, nrow = (nrow(links3)), ncol = 19)
coor <- matrix(, nrow = (nrow(links3)), ncol = 3)


for (i in 1:(nrow(links3))){
x <- links3[i,1]
doc <- read_html(paste0(x))
val <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[1]/h3/b"))
if(val=="<b>Tipo Inmueble</b>"){
basedes[i,1] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[1]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,2] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[3]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,3] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[5]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,4] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[7]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,5] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[9]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,6] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[11]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,7] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[13]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,8] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[15]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,9] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[17]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,10] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[19]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,11] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[21]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,12] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[23]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,13] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[1]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,14] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[3]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,15] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[5]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,16] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[7]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,17] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[9]/h3/b"))
basedes[i,18] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[11]/h3/b"))

base[i,1] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="*//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[2]/h4"))
base[i,2] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[4]/h4"))
base[i,3] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[6]/h4"))
base[i,4] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[8]/h4"))
base[i,5] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[10]/h4"))
base[i,6] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[12]/h4"))
base[i,7] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[14]/h4"))
base[i,8] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[16]/h4"))
base[i,9] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//***[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[18]/h4"))
base[i,10] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[20]/h4"))
base[i,11] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[22]/h4"))
base[i,12] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[1]/li[24]/h4"))
base[i,13] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[2]/h4"))
base[i,14] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[4]/h4"))
base[i,15] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[6]/h4"))
base[i,16] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[8]/h4"))
base[i,17] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[10]/h4"))
base[i,18] <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//*[@id='info_nombre']/ul[2]/li[12]/h4"))


lon <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="*//input[@type='hidden']"))
lon <- gsub(".*longitud", "", lon)
lon <- gsub("/>.*", "", lon)
lon <- gsub("value=", "", lon)
lon <- gsub("\"", "", lon)
lon <- gsub(" ", "", lon)
coor[i,1] <- lon

lat <- toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="*//input[@type='hidden']"))
lat <- gsub(".*latitud", "", lat)
lat <- gsub("/>.*", "", lat)
lat <- gsub("value=", "", lat)
lat <- gsub("\"", "", lat)
lat <- gsub(" ", "", lat)
coor[i,2] <- lat

cod<-  toString(xml_find_all(doc, xpath="*//div[@class='code']"))
cod <- gsub(".*web: ", "", cod)
cod <- gsub("<.*", "", cod)
coor[i,3] <- cod
remove(val)
remove(lat)
remove(lon)
}else{}
}
```

But after approximately 5000 iterations I receive the following message:

```
r for windows gui frontend stopped working
```

I have to close R session and start again.

I have looked my system configuration and It shows the following:

```
Processes: 93;
CPU Usage 6%;
Physical Memory: 51%;
RAM:8.0 GB;
Windows 7;
```

Why I'm having this message? How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you just run it on the command line? I haven't read through all of the code, but are there any pop-ups or graphs or anything like that at any point? If so, disable them. If not, run from the command line.

Comment: Actually I ran the code with a .bat file in to different computers: "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "~\script.R" also with R studio  and I have the same problem. My R version is: R-3.2.2

Comment: Well, for starters I'd avoid `toString()` and there's prbly a far more optimal way to get to the data but we have no idea what your data actually is since you didn't provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not 100% clear from the data and code you have given here what the problem is. However, when you are creating a lot of variables. Each variable lives in active memory, in your RAM.

And despite the configuration at 51%, depending on your system, whether or not there are any java packages in play and your use of garbage collection you could be running out of usable RAM available to R and its subprocesses.

If it were me hitting this problem and I was sure the source was not crashing me (by going to the actual iterations it crashes on directly and check for errors or bad data one at a time) or that the script had a bug in it, I would look at what my data needs are, which of the variables created need to persist for the next step and which do not.

Then I would aggressively use `rm()` and `gc()` to remove and garbage collect to clear out the cruft and see if it goes further the next time. You may need to do this at a few steps *INSIDE* your loop to remove byproducts that are not clearing themselves.

If you cannot purge any of the data acquired, then I would still use `rm()` and `gc()` to remove some of the needed data just to see if it continues through the entire loop. If it does, then you know that it is in fact a memory management issue.

Now it becomes about writing a script that gathers data in bunches, converts it to the most compact format and stores it in persistent memory until all the processing is done, then loads it into RAM for you analysis. You can use csv's or json files.

R is a fabulously powerful language that works very well in many circumstances, but demands that you manage interim data and variables well when the data gets large. A simple table may persist in as many as 4 instances depending on how it is manipulated and managed. So, if you have a properly functioning script, then you will need to work on how you manage what you get out of that script and bring it back into the analytical process.

For me, I tend to work at big files like I would eat an entire cow, one bite at a time. Poke into static memory for values as needed and update static files as you go.

I hope this helps.